# Magento native URL Redirect not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have an **old** link https://www.musclenutrition.com/listaprodotti.php?cat=Dimagranti
Need to be redirected to the **new** : https://www.musclenutrition.com/integratori/dimagranti.html

I used the URL Rewrite function in Magento, but as you can see by clicking the old link it's not working.

Anybody has an idea?

[image]

Comment: While I appreciate the clarity of what you specifically want, you have shown no effort into actually creating a `.htaccess` file on which the answer depends.

Comment: I'm *fairly* sure this won't work because Magento, like mod_rewrite, uses the **path** not the **path + querystring** ...

Comment: Hi Xorifelse, it's not clear to me, sorry, does Magento provide an all inclusive solution for URL redirect? Should I add something? All others redirects in the table are working, thousands and thousands. I'm using  that table because obviously I need to add more urls.

Comment: Hi CD001, please let me understand what's wrong, should I add only "listaprodotti.php" ? then how can I tell different pages? ex. "listaprodotti.php?cat=Dimagranti" from "listaprodotti.php?cat=Proteine"

Answer (score 0):

Is the **old** link coming from a previous website and you wish to inform search engines about the new urls?

If so, this can't be done through Magento's URL Rewrite Management but since you are using Nginx, the use of the htaccess file is useless.

You need to use Nginx's Rewrite (or Return) Directive as explained here:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Don't forget to make 301 redirects to make the change permanent for the search engines.

Hope it helps.